# Java How to initialize instance variable when there's type mismatch

Tags: java, initialization, type-conversion, type-mismatch

How do I initialize an instance variable when there's type mismatch?

```
public class Djia implements Comparable<Djia>{
      // instance variables
      private GregorianCalendar date; 
      private double opening;
      private double closing; 

      public Djia(String dt, double opening, double closing){

          this.date=dt;  // **** Type mismatch, can't convert from String to GregorianCalendar****

          this.opening=opening;
          this.closing=closing;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your String `dt` to GregorianCalendar `date`

Sample :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("ddmmyyyy").withOffsetParsed();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("dt");
GregorianCalendar cal = dateTime.toGregorianCalendar();
```

Then assign :

```
this.date = cal;
```

This will not give error in Casting

Comment: joda time is not a part of JRE (at least JRE7). I think DateFormat is the better way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the input to the correct object type.  In this case, use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` or similar to read the String and output a date.  You will either need a well-defined date format (e.g. yyyy/MM/dd) or else define one formatter per format and select the correct one by analysing the input.

Answer (score 1):

`this.date=dt;` you can't do this here, as `date` is a `Date` object and `dt` is a `String`.

This is what you might be looking : 
`this.date =  new SimpleDateFormat("YOUR FORMAT").parse(dt);` (considering that `dt`here is your date in String)